# Using groupby, shift and rolling in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to calculate rolling averages within groups. For this task I want a rolling average from the rows above so thought the easiest way would be to use `shift()` and then do `rolling()`. The problem is that `shift()` shifts the data from previous groups which makes first row in group 2 and 3 incorrect. Column 'ma' should have NaN in rows 4 and 7. How can I achieve this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Group": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
     "Value": [2.5, 2.9, 1.6, 9.1, 5.7, 8.2, 4.9, 3.1, 7.5]
     })

df = df.sort_values(['Group'])
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df['ma'] = df.groupby('Group', as_index=False)['Value'].shift(1).rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean()

print(df)
```

I get this:

```
   index  Group  Value    ma
0      0      1    2.5   NaN
1      3      1    9.1  2.50
2      6      1    4.9  5.80
3      1      2    2.9  5.80
4      4      2    5.7  6.00
5      7      2    3.1  4.30
6      2      3    1.6  4.30
7      5      3    8.2  3.65
8      8      3    7.5  4.90
```

I tried answers from couple similar questions but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Your minimum period is 1. How can you have NaN ?

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh because of the shift function. The first row won't have a previous row. So essentially it has 0 previous periods, resulting in NaN.

Comment: @SoSincere3 Thank you for the explanation. Not sure if I posted the response. Maybe someone hacked my account. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, then the solution you require can be achieved in 2 steps using the following:

```
df['sa'] = df.groupby('Group', as_index=False)['Value'].transform(lambda x: x.shift(1))

df['ma'] = df.groupby('Group', as_index=False)['sa'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean())
```

I got the below output, where 'ma' is the desired column

```
index   Group   Value   sa  ma
0   0   1   2.5     NaN     NaN
1   3   1   9.1     2.5     2.5
2   6   1   4.9     9.1     5.8
3   1   2   2.9     NaN     NaN
4   4   2   5.7     2.9     2.9
5   7   2   3.1     5.7     4.3
6   2   3   1.6     NaN     NaN
7   5   3   8.2     1.6     1.6
8   8   3   7.5     8.2     4.9
```

Edit: Example with one groupby

```
def shift_ma(x):
    return x.shift(1).rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean()

df['ma'] = df.groupby('Group', as_index=False)['Value'].apply(shift_ma).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Why doesn't it work in one step without `transform()`?

Comment: When you do 'shift(1)' , you are closing the grouped part. Now when you call 'rolling', it works on a non grouped dataframe. Hence your rolling is spilling across groups, coz the groups were lost when 'shift' was called. Essentially, you need two separate 'groupby', one for 'shift', and another for rolling mean. Transform has no special value in this case. You can try your own version with 2 'groupby' and simply 'shift', then 'rolling mean'. I use transform whenever the length of new column has to be same as the parent column. Force of habit :)

Comment: There is no reason to use 2 groupby's. One groupby with `apply` should be enough to solve this.

Comment: Yes, Andy. That would do it too. I just followed one train of thought. Thanks for the alternative

Comment: could you add an example with one `groupby` and `apply`? thanks!